# Outlook email in Applescript - can't make into type text error

Tags: macos, concatenation, applescript

I am using Applescript to generate an email in Outlook and am attempting to combine two items (from two different variables) for the `content` field. My items have the following format:

```
set selectedstring to item myindex of myList -- selected string is "string1"
```

And are used this way:

```
set theEmailText to (selectedstring) & "additional text"

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"The Subject", content:theEmailText}
    open newMessage
    get newMessage
end tell
```

But when I run this script, I receive the following error:

```
Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t make {"string1", "additional text"} into type text.
```

Is there an additional step I need to take to get this into a string that can be used for the `content` field?

Comment: According to the error, `selectedstring` is a list, so the concatenation operator is adding the additional text to that list - just coerce it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Coercing the list to a string as follows worked, thanks to [red_menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10853463/red-menace):

```
content:theEmailText as string
```